# How to append request contexts while they have different receiver implementation

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

In google io 2011, David Chandler mentioned that you can chain different request context by using append() method,but in practice, I don't know how to chain them up while they have different receiver,using to() and then fire()?

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two kinds of receivers: the ones bound to each method invocation (that you pass to the `Request`'s `to()` method), and the context-level one (that you pass to the `RequestContext`'s `fire()` method). The `Request`'s `fire(Receiver)` method is a short-hand for `to(receiver).fire()`, i.e. it binds the `Receiver` to the method.

The method-level receivers depend on the method only, their generic parameterization depends on the method's return value (the generic parameterization of the `Request` or `InstanceRequest`), so whether you `append()` several `RequestContext`s together changes absolutely nothing.

The context-level receiver is always parameterized with `Void`. When you `append()` contexts together, they actually form a single context with several *interfaces*, so you only call `fire()` once, on any one of the appended contexts.

Now let's go back to the basics: without using `append()`, you can only *batch* together calls for methods that are declared on the context interface. If you have two distinct context interfaces you want to use, you have to make two `fire()`, i.e. two HTTP requests. The introduction of `append()` allows you to batch together calls for methods declared on any context interface: simply append a context to another one and the calls on both contexts will be batched together in the same HTTP request, triggered by a unique `fire()` on any one of the context being appended.

Now into the technical details: internally, a context is nothing more than a thin wrapper around a *state* object. When you `edit()` or `create()` a proxy, you add it to the internal *state*, and when you call a service method, the method name (actually, its obfuscated *token*) and the arguments are captured and pushed to the *state* as well. When you `append()` a context, you're only making it share its internal *state* with the one of the context you append it to. That way, when you call a service method on the appended context, its pushed on the exact same *state* as the one of the other context, and when you `fire()` any one of them, the state is serialized into a single HTTP request.
Note that, to append a context, its own internal state has to be empty, otherwise an exception will be raised, as the state would be thrown away to be replaced by the one of the other context.

In brief, and in practice:

```java
FirstContext first = rf.first();
SomeProxy proxy = first.create(SomeProxy.class);
...
SecondContext second = first.append(rf.second());
OtherProxy other = second.create(OtherProxy.class);
other.setSome(proxy);
...
second.saveAndReturnSelf(other).to(new Receiver<OtherProxy>() {
   ...
});
...
first.fire();
```

Note that the line that creates and appends the second context could equally be written:

```java
SecondContext second = rf.second();
first.append(second);
```

The `append` method returns its argument as a convenience, but it's really the same value you passed as the argument. This is only to allow writing the one-liner above, instead of being *forced* to use the two-liner.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I am expecting your answer, glad you really answered.This is really helping by clarify everything up.It's really big deal to me.